# Defining arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Just got a quick array question it might be a little stupid but im kind of new to coding, what is the difference between the code here:

```
var items:[String]
```

so from my understanding here you are defining the variable 'items' as an empty array string. items is of type array

```
var items: [String] = ()
```

here you are defining items as an empty array but shouldn't it written as:

```
 var items = [String]()
```

or is this essentially the same code

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
var items:[String]
```

means that you are declaring a variable named `items` that will be an array of `String` instances.  However, you are not initializing that variable to any initial value.  The compiler will not let you use this variable before it is initialized with a value, because you are not declaring the type (`[String]`) to be optional (`[String]?`), so it *must* be initialized and contain a non-nil value to be used by your code.

This:

```
var items: [String] = ()
```

means that you are declaring a variable named `items` that should be an array of `String` instances, but you are trying to initialized it with the value `()`, which in Swift is synonymous with `Void`.  The compiler will not allow this. A similar, valid notation would be: `var items: [String] = []` which uses an empty array of unspecified type (`[]`) to initialize the value. Since you declared `items` to be an array of `String` values, the compiler can infer that the untyped empty array (`[]`) should be an empty array of `String` values (`[String]`) and will allow it.

This:

```
var items = [String]()
```

is declaring a variable named `items` that you aren't explicitly specifying the type for, and immediately initializing it with an empty array of `String` values.  From this, the compiler can infer the type of the variable is `[String]` so you don't need to declare it.

Comment: The first example will compile – in Swift you can defer the initialisation of a variable (or constant). You simply have to ensure that it's initialised before it's read.

Comment: Please add the other valid initialisers, e.g. `var x:[String] = []`, and the variants using `Array<String>` to make your answer comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

`var items = [String]()` is called initializer syntax. It means you're allocating memory for the future storage of an array of strings.

However, by doing `var items:[String]` you are not providing an initializer. This will cause an error--consider conceptually that you are pointing to an area of memory that you have not allocated space for. There's nowhere for additional variables to go!

On the other hand, `var items: [String] = ()` doesn't seem to be any kind of standard syntax. It seems like you're casting an array of strings as void. This shouldn't compile.